# Android Studio adds libraries.iml file

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've just created a *Multi project setup for my Android project in Android Studio as suggested by [Gradle Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Dependencies-Android-Libraries-and-Multi-project-setup). Here* is the file structure I have

```
MyProject/
 | settings.gradle
 | build.gradle
 | MyProject.iml
 + app/
    | build.gradle
    | app.iml
 + libraries/
    + lib1/
       | build.gradle
       | lib1.iml
```

There is three modules in this configuration - `MyProjects.iml`, `app.iml` and `lib1.iml`. Although everything works just fine and project builds successfully, there is one annoying issue with it. Android Studio constantly creates a `libraries.iml` file under `libraries` folder and makes that folder a module.

That's why is the question. Is this a normal behaviour and - if not - how to get rid of it?

I tried to remove `libraries.iml` file and update `MyProject.iml` with no luck. The file appears again and again.

**Update & final solution:**
To avoid all that hassle with generated files distracting our attention, I configured Android Studio to not show them at the end.

```
File (Android Studio on Mac) -> Preferences... -> File Types -> Ignore
files and folders: .DS_Store;.git;*.iml;.idea;
```

Comment: Why you don't like *.iml files?

Comment: Because ´libraries´ is just a folder, not a module. Not sure I want intelliJ to create a module out of every folder.

Answer (score 5):

You specified 'libraries' as a parent module for your 'lib1' module.
If you do not need to have such parent module, you can change your settings.gradle
from

```
include ':app', ':libraries:lib1'
```

to

```
include ':app', 'libraries/lib1'
```

Comment: Why do you say "you specified 'libraries' as a parent module"? @beworker only put the real library inside a folder

Comment: @Jose_GD because gradle creates such modules if you use ":" separator. you can check it using the following task:
`task listProjects << {
    rootProject.allprojects.each {
        println it
    }
}`

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior and there is nothing wrong in it.

As per my finding there are two types of .iml files inside your project

1. Inside modules(where your code resides)
2. Inside Project Root (Where your module resides)

[image: project structure iml files]

As you can see in the picture

Files marked red are root .iml files which doesn't have more info inside them whereas  files marked yellow are your actual module's .iml files which have all information about your module like dependency, tasks etc.

You will have more clear picture if you will have a look in to these files.